# ¿Hay alguna forma de volver a consumir el mensaje de un topico de kafka si un correo no se envía???esto en spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kafka

¿Hay alguna forma de volver a consumir el mensaje de un topico de kafka si un correo no se envía?esto en spring boot, cabe mencionar que si el correo no se envia es problema del **relay de correo** y no kafka, pero quisiera indicarle al consumidor que vuelva a consumir el mensaje cuentas veces sea necesario hasta enviar el correo con el mismo mensaje ¿habra alguna forma de hacerlo y como podría indicarle al consumidor que vuelva a consumir el mismo mensaje??

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso estas imaginando el uso de las colas de Kafka de una forma errónea, la cola se encarga de repartir el mensaje entre los consumidores no es una base de datos que te mantendrá el mensaje indefinidamente.

Las opciones que tienes son:

1. Volver a encolar el mensaje ya se a la misma cola o a una diferente, debes de tener cuidado según la frecuencia del error que no vaya a realizar un ciclo infinito de mensajes erróneos que vuelven a la cola, por eso se suelen gestionar estos casos en una cola diferente para llevar el control y gestionarlos como reintentos.
2. Que el servicio gestione los reintentos en código o que el mensaje se pesista en una base de datos mientras gestionas el envió.

Comment: Hola Roben E Moran te agradezco la repuesta, en cuanto al volver encolar mi mensaje realiza un ciclo infinito como bien lo dijiste, voy a intentar encolar el mensaje en otro topico y checar el comportamiento. Una pregunta mas , he invetigado un poco sobre pausar el consumidor pero en algunos articulos menciona que no es muy viable ya que suele suceder que al reanudar el consumidor no recupera todos los mensajes ?Que tan cierto es esto ? de antemano agradezco la ayuda. Saludos